# JAVA: How can I add SWING components to my game HUD with custom textures

Tags: java, swing, components, coordinates

-- Little note, I attempted to upload an image of my game to illustrate my question, however I do not yet have the required reputation to do so. I apollogise for this.

I would like to create a drop down screen from the top HUD element on my game which the player can type into, effectively becoming a chat window, the actually window is not an issue and I understand that you can disable background and boarder rendering of Java's Swing components so that isn't an issue.

My question is simple, can I take advantage of java's Swing components like JTextField and position them exactly within the bounds of this area, without having to deal with java's layout classes. So this is a summary:

- How do I set the final size of the swing components *MANUALLY* and
- How do I set coordinates of the components *MANUALLY* **With out using a layout manager**

Comment: Yes, you can, no you don't want to. Reasoning, you will have to become responsible for taking into consideration the variations of how different rendering pipelines work and affect the size the components would like to be. The Swing API has been designed around the the layout management API, which includes synchronising updates and changes to component states. This functionality already exists and you should find away to work within those confines to gain the greatest flexibility and ease of use...of course, you could simply spend the rest of your life implementing hacks to resolve issues...

Comment: upload your image to an image sharing service, then post a link **to the image**, not to the web page, here, and we can edit your question and post your image for you.

Comment: I currently cannot upload it as all of those sites are blocked on my school network, However I can tell you that it is a tile based game with 16x16 size tiles, aka very low resolution. Is there a way that you could give a detail explain how I would implement this correctly with Swing. PS I am self-taught so all knowledge I have is limited. The box for the window will move down onto the screen and up, that is why I wanted to be able to set its coordinates as it has to move... sorry for any inconveniences.

Comment: My "gut" feeling is, if you really need "more" control over the placement of the components, you create a layout manager, which can take the position you want, but which can still control the sizing of the component.  You might need to provide more hints about how much space the component should occupy, but you should try and abstract the concept as much as possible and steer away from providing pixel measurements, as this the core of the problem...

Comment: It will occupy 9/11 width and 5/7 height of the screen, however my game window cannot be re-sized if this helps the solution, but yes, your "gut" feeling is correct, I thought that it was better to use a Swing component than to code it from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use a null layout on the container and call `setBounds(...)` on the component to MANUALLY place them. And this is usually a VERY BAD THING to do as it forces you to paint yourself into a layout corner making it very hard to upgrade or enhance your GUI later. It also guarantees that your GUI will look terrible on all platforms and screen resolutions other than one. Many newbies usually go this route initially, and then most leave it eventually after gaining more experience with Swing as they run into its failings, weaknesses and limitations.

For a more complete answer, consider giving more specifics and in image (we can help with this) of your GUI layout requirements.